# Why is UserService bean needed during tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I start my test - I have application context failed to load and UserService bean is missing. But why do I even need it here?

Here is my simple test

```java
@WebMvcTest(RestaurantController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)

public class RestaurantControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    RestaurantService restaurantService;


    RestaurantResponseDTO restaurantDominos = new RestaurantResponseDTO(1, "Dominos", "street2", 3);
    RestaurantResponseDTO restaurantMamamia = new RestaurantResponseDTO(2, "Mamamia", "random street1", 14);
    RestaurantResponseDTO restaurantAndriano = new RestaurantResponseDTO(3, "Adriano's pizza", "street3", 2);

    @Test
    public void getAllRestaurants() throws Exception {
        List<RestaurantResponseDTO> restaurantsResponse = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
                restaurantDominos, restaurantMamamia, restaurantAndriano));

        Mockito.when(restaurantService.getAll()).thenReturn(restaurantsResponse);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/restaurant")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(3)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[2].name", is("Jane Doe")));
    }

}
```

Here is my Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/restaurant")
public class RestaurantController {

    RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @Autowired
    public RestaurantController(RestaurantService restaurantService) {
        this.restaurantService = restaurantService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<RestaurantResponseDTO> getAll() {
        return restaurantService.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public RestaurantResponseDTO getOne(@PathVariable int id) {
        return restaurantService.getById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@RequestBody @Valid RestaurantCreationDTO restaurantCreationDTO,
                       BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throwExceptionIfBindingResultHasErrors(bindingResult);
        }
        restaurantService.create(restaurantCreationDTO);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public RestaurantResponseDTO update(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody
    @Valid  RestaurantCreationDTO restaurantCreationDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throwExceptionIfBindingResultHasErrors(bindingResult);
        }
        return restaurantService.update(id, restaurantCreationDTO);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        restaurantService.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Here is my Spring security Config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/vote/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/profile").authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()

                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return daoProvider;
        }
    }

And here is my UserService

    @Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with email: " + email);
        }
        return new AuthenticatedUser(user);
    }

    public User registerNewUserAccount(UserDTO userDto) throws UserAlreadyExistException {
        String email = userDto.getEmail();
        if (ifUserExists(email)) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistException("There is an account with that email address: "
                    + email);
        }

        User user = toUser(userDto);

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
    public User toUser(UserDTO userDto) {
        return new User(userDto.getUsername(), userDto.getEmail(),
                userDto.getPassword());
    }

    private boolean ifUserExists(String email) {
        return userRepository.findUserByEmail(email) != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a `@WebMvcTest` which will also start security when that is configured, hence it needs to be available.

Comment: @M.Deinum but how can I turn it off for this class? @AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false) does not work.

Comment: That will only disable the registration of the filters, not bootstrapping security. You can add an excludeFilter for your security configuration and also disable the spring security auto configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for your answer! I feel I bit desperate right now as I dunno what to do.
Could you please clarify, is it possible to turn off this bootstrap in tests?

@WebMvcTest(value = UserRestaurantController.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
does not help.

Comment: You also need to exclude your own security configuration class. The auto configuration doesn't kick in because of this. So you need to exclude your own configuration as well, using the excludeFilter.

Comment: @M.Deinum God bless you)